# NiFi - Control de order merging two dataflows with EnforceOrder and MergeContent processor

Tags: apache-nifi, merge-file

I am trying to use the EnforceOrder processor to do a Merge in a determinate order. To do so, this is my flow: 
[image]

In the updateAttribute, I am generating an attribute to set order I want in the merge.
On the one of the left, I am setting the value '1' and on the other, I am setting the value of '2'.

[image]

And then the configuration of the EnforceOrder is the nextone:

[image]

The problem is that only arrives the flow of the **process.order = 1** and is not taking out the number 2. What am I doing wrong?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use **`EnforceOrder`** processor to control the order of flowfiles reaching to ***`MergeContent`*** processor.

- using `UpdateAttribute` processor add the sequence number to the flowfile.

**Example:**

- Consider 2 flowfiles, **Flowfile-2**(this content will need to showup first) will have lower `sequence number` compared to **flowfile1** then feed the `success` connection to **`MergeContent`** processor, By using enforceorder processor we are making sure flowfile2 will be going to **Mergecontent** processor before flowfile1.

Please refer to [this](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/222881/nifi-merge-header-and-data-coming-from-different-f.html) and use the enforce-order template to get familiar with the `enforce order` processor.

**UPDATE:**

I think the issue is with the EnforceOrder configs,

- **Group Identifier** is configured as **`${filename}`** so if you have two different filenames then processor doesn't wait for both of them.
- To fix this Keep **common attribute** in **`UpdateAttribute`** processors like `group_name` as gn then use same attribute name in **Group Identifier** property value as **`${group_name}`**
- Connect **`Skipped and Wait`** connections to EnforceOrder processor it self.

***UpdateAttributeConfigs:***

[image]

***EnforceOrderConfigs:***
[image]

Please use [this](https://github.com/shureddy/NiFiTemplates/blob/master/enforce-order.xml) template as reference and upload it to your NiFi instance check out how the flow has been running.

Comment: Can you put an example of the configuration of the updateattribute and the EnforceOrder? I am only having one output instead of two.

Comment: @jmarco10, That's intresting, in question there is another dataflow so i thought you are having another flowfile. Could you please update the `question` with more details about your flow and how your `input flowfile` going to `Enforce Order` and `expected output`.

Comment: @jmarco10, Please checkout my Edited answer's **`UPDATE`** section.